# Calling JS function before it is defined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In the body we have elements that when clicked, invoke JS function like following:

```
<div class="radio-box" onclick="setDeliveryMethod('method_1')">
```

at the end of the body we define the function like following:

```
function setDeliveryMethod(dMethod){
   ...
}
```

This is done close to the end of the body, because we need some dynamic values to be loaded and added by PHP.

There are no issues on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, however IE does not run the function and gives `'setDeliveryMethod' is undefined error`

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce in IE11 given your code. Can you edit a snippet into the question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: which IE is affected? Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, based on your code and description, I create a sample, everything works well. Try to put the JavaScript function at the front of the div tag, or in the header. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).